# Azure Functions - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an ARM template that populates a resource group with a Durable Function (C# .Net Core 3.1) and storage account.

The function app contains a durable function that's triggered uses the RabbitMQ binding to collect a message from a queue.

This has been working fine but this morning while making a minor change to the arm template VS Code suggested I update the schema version - no problem I thought! The deployment that followed messed things up so I deleted the function app and storage account and ran again. That time the deployment ran ok. However, now when the app starts, nothing is collected from the queue and I find the following in the function host log file:

> Error indexing method 'ConsumeNewClientEntryPoint' ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException : None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed) ---> Connection failed ---> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. xx.x.37.141:5672

The ip address given in the error message is that for the RabbitMQ host the binding uses.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad! I'd forgotten to enable vnet integration on the newly deployed Function App (should be part of ARM template)